# couchbase cbtransfer hangs at 75% while processing 4 million documents

Tags: couchbase

I am currently facing a problem while trying to to do cbtransfer from a node to the filesystem (this is to backup the existing data). The total number of documents in the bucket is 4387914. Out of these the cbtransfer process always stops after writing 3289800 documents to the file. The file size stands at 1.5 GB and the progress of the cbtransfer is always shown as 75%.

I have already tried to use the cbb_max_mb and batch_max_size by setting them to lower values 10 and 10 respectively but the freeze happens at the same point.

The couchbase version is 3.0.1 community edition.

Has someone run into this error before? If yes, how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask why you're running cbtransfer and not cbbackup or cbbackupwrapper? The cbtransfer tool is a low level tool that is really meant  to be used as a last resort when you need to transfer data off of a non-responsive server. I would highly recommend using the cbbackup or cbbackupwrapper tools instead.

Comment: Well, i started out with cbtransfer as that is the first google result :). On the other hand cbbackup gives me the same result and hangs at the exact same point (probably because it is built on the top of cbtransfer). cbbackupwrapper is in from version 4.0 i think. I am on 3.0.1 :(

Comment: Can you review the log files and see if there is an error generated? Please update us on the results of your log file search.